# Is it possible to create more than one global CSS file in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I would have two global CSS files in my application, so I try to do it by:

- creating new file (as sibling of `styles.css` in the folder structure)
- add lines in `angular.json` in: "build" -> "styles" and "test" -> "styles".

Unfortunately it doesn't work, so my question is: did I make something wrong or is it impossible to have two global CSS files supported by Angular (I skipped option with adding css file in `index.html`)?

Comment: Seems to work fine in a StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvje8u?file=angular.json

Comment: 1. I didn't see in debugger->web to see that my file is downloaded. 2. Class-style didn't apply (I even tried to paste same style in styles.css to compare and style is good).

Comment: I don't think you will see it being downloaded, because I believe the build process adds it into the index.html file

Comment: File 'styles.css' is visible in debugger so I think my own should be too. I test method from source post in stackblitz and there it works. I don't know what the difference in my app that it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you make sure to stop the app, and do `ng serve` again?

Comment: user184994 write answer of my question, because that's an correct answer. I will mark it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to `angular.json` are not picked up automatically.

You will need to stop the app, and do `ng serve` again